# MacOS Mojave: An error occurred while verifying firmware

Tags: macos

I have Mid 2014 Macbook pro machine and running OS macOS Sierra 10.12.6. Now I am trying to upgrade my OS then may mac getting hanged after restart until battery drain after that I am getting An error occurred while verifying firmware. Also machine date is being change to 1st Jan, 2015. Kindly provide me solution if someone knows how figure out it.

Comment: Note, the firmware updates are rolled into macOS and don’t really require APFS or HFS. !  Try starting in Single user mode and fixing your disk.